# I'm getting this error using React Native and Sanity: Unable to resolve "get-random-values-esm" from "sanity\node_modules\sanity\lib\index.js"

Tags: react-native, npm, expo, sanity

I'm using sanity and react-native with expo to create an app. but on the mobile devices I get the error using expo  go.

i've tried deleting node_modules folder, and re-intstalling the node_models, i've deleted the dependency resolve "get-random-values-esm" from the package.js and re-installed the node modules. Still noting.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing

```
https://github.com/sanity-io/get-random-values-esm
```

Then delete your node_modules and reinstall the sanity client.

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I installed the package you mentioned, I also tried to add the override specified here https://github.com/sanity-io/sanity/issues/4595 in order to solve this but without luck.